# Deleting holes of contour polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, contour, holes

I'm trying to create hypsometric areas from a DEM. My current workflow in QGIS is:

1. Extracting contours with SAGA, as I need contours from specific elevations (250, 500, 1000...) and not just every x meters.
2. Converting the contours from multipart to singlepart, and then to polygon after fixing geometries.

The problem is, the resulting polygon has other polygons inside it that should be holes of the first polygon [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsvne.jpg). I can't seem to find a way to "substract" them, and I've been searching all over Google for days. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try **Union** and then **Delete duplicate geometries** tools.

Comment: **gdal Contour Polygons** seem to produce non overlapping contours